# how can I quickly get answer of LCM by python

Tags: python, lcm

```
def getLCM(a, b):
    c, d = max(a, b), min(a, b)
    while c != d:
        temp = c - d
        c, d = max(temp, d), min(temp, d)

    return a * b // c


def nlcm(num):
    temp = 1
    while len(num) != 0:
        temp = getLCM(temp, num[-1])
        num.pop()
    return temp

print(nlcm([2,6,8,14,5]));
```

I need to "quickly" get answer this problem.
in test case, my code is very slow.

Comment: Couldn't you find something else to do in that 0.023 seconds it took to run that program? Maybe grab a coffee or play with the kids :-)

Comment: i am getting an answer instantaneously on my machine.. are you timing in milliseconds?

Comment: Maybe number of num is large, my code is slow. So I need to get fast my code

Answer (score 2):

There are existing `gcd` implementations in Python, and LCM is definable in terms of `gcd`, so you may as well avoid reinventing the wheel. Specifically:

> gcd(a, b) x lcm(a, b) = a x b

With Python 3.5 and higher, there is an accelerated `gcd` function on the `math` module, so `lcm` can simplify to:

```
from math import gcd

def getLCM(a, b):
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)
```

On older Python, it's not accelerated, but `fractions.gcd` is a decent implementation provided for you, so you can use it instead, or to use the best possible `gcd` on whatever version you run on, a nested import attempt works:

```
try:
    from math import gcd
except ImportError:
    from fractions import gcd
```

Your `nlcm` loop could also be simplified: You don't need to destructively iterate manually, just loop:

```
def nlcm(num):
    temp = 1
    for x in num:
        temp = getLCM(temp, x)
    return temp
```

Or if you want to get clever, use `reduce` (`functools.reduce` on Python 3.x) since it does exactly what that simplified loop is already doing:

```
from functools import reduce

def nlcm(nums):
    return reduce(getLCM, nums, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. thanks to you, I know about the 'reduce'. But in my study class, I can't use function 'gcd'.

Comment: @전현근: Well, you can still use `fractions.gcd` as a better implementation, since [the code for it is pure Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/fractions.py#L17) and can literally be copied; just make sure you understand it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "long execution" is not in the example you provided but rather with bigger inputs, you can add memoization and increate the time `getLCM()` is calculated in case it's called again with the same numbers:

```
hash = dict() # we'll save here the calculated results

def getLCM(a, b):
    global hash
    if (a, b) in hash:  # if it was already calculated
        return hash[(a, b)]  # use the cached result
    c, d = max(a, b), min(a, b)
    while c != d:
        temp = c - d
        c, d = max(temp, d), min(temp, d)

    hash[(a, b)] = a * b // c. # cash the result
    return a * b // c
```

Comment: Note: If you're on Python 3.2 or higher, [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) can give you this caching behavior as a decorator on the original (uncached) function, avoiding the ugliness of mixing the caching logic with the computational logic.

Comment: True, though you have to take into account that this caching is... LRU meaning, remembers only the most recently numbers. And since it's limited in size - you should ensure that it fits your application behavior.

Comment: The name is slightly inaccurate. The *default* is LRU with a 128 entry bound, but it can be made infinite trivially (you just pass `None` as the `maxsize`). It runs faster that way too (no overhead dealing with cache eviction).

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks I wasn't aware of that!